# Block only voice messages in Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I really dislike voicemail or voice messsages as they:

- Are much slower to process than text
- Don't allow the sender to revise their message (leading to rambling)
- Can't be skimmed to know when to listen to them or which parts to focus on
- Can't be easily reviewed for any data contained in them

I just want to block reception of voice messages entirely, but it seems I can only block all kinds of incoming messages from a person, which would include text.

How can I block only incoming voice messages?